# pick out the true statement in metric spaces?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let {X, d} be a metric space and let E ⊂ X. For x ∈ X, define

d(x, E) =    inf d(x,y) where y ∈ E

Pick out the true statements:

(a) |d(x, E) − d(y, E)| ≤ d(x, y) for all x and y ∈ X.

(b) d(x, E) = d(x, m) for some m ∈ E

My attempt : i was taking X = R-{O} , E =(0,∞) and x= -1

```
        now for option (a) by triangle inequality  it will satisfied.....and 
   it is correct
```

i don't know  about the second option (b).

Pliz help me and tell me the solution,,,,,i would be thankful

Comment: Is E a closed subset?

Comment: I don't understand how you are using the Triangle Inequality...you are correct that the statement is true but I think you need to strengthen your argument.

Comment: E may be closed or open,,,,,,,not sure it is closed  @ salahamam-Fatima

Comment: i mean   d(x,E) - d(y,E) ≤ d(x,y) ≤ d(x,E)  + d(y,E) @ lulu

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please use it: you've been here long enough . . .

Answer (score 0):

You have come to the correct conclusion about statement (a) albeit for the wrong reasons.  A valid line of reasoning is as follows:

> Given $z \in E$, we note that
>   $$
> d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)
> $$
>   Since this is true for all $z \in E$, we can conclude that
>   $$
> d(x,E) = \inf_{z \in E} d(x,z) \leq
> \inf_{z \in E} [d(x,y) + d(y,z)] = 
> d(x,y) + \inf_{z \in E} d(y,z) =
> d(x,y) + d(y,E)
> $$
>   using this "standard triangle inequality", we can deduce the "reverse triangle inequality".

As for part (b): consider $x = 0$ and $E = (1,2)$ under the usual metric for $\Bbb R$.

Comment: thanks a lots @ omnomnomnom,,,but for option b) ,,acording to ur answer d(x,E) = d(x,m) = 0...so option B is also correct   ...Am i right ?

Comment: No, not if E is open.  For example take E= (1, 2) in R and x= 0.  Then for any p in E, d(x, p)= |p- 0|= p since p is positive so  d(x, E)= inf (|p|) = 1.  But 1 itself is not in the open interval (1, 2) so for all p in (1, 2), |p|> 1.

Comment: im not getting ,, how can u claim that d(x, E) = inf(P) = 1 @user247327

Comment: @kalomlego No, for my example, $d(x,E) = 1$.  Note that there is no $m \in E$ such that $d(x,m) = 1$.

Comment: @ omnomnomnom..one last  doubt  suppose i take m = (4/3,3/2) ∈ (1,2)...in this case i think d(x,E) = d(x,m),,,,,for some m ∈  E

Comment: $(4/3,3/2)$ is not an element of $(1,2)$; both of these are intervals.  In any case, we have $d(x,m) = 4/3 \neq d(x,E)$.  In particular, note that $1 \notin E$.

Comment: okkk,,,thanks a lot once again @ omnomnomnom.. im voting up ur answer now